# Update using two unique fields

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

There are two tables

1. |   table_1 | periodically TRUNCATE and INSERT updated information
2. |   table_2 | rows are updated based on data from table_1

the first and second tables have a unique index for the **lap, tt** fields

My current request to update via

```
INSERT INTO public.table_2 ... VALUES (...) ON CONFLICT (lap,tt) DO UPDATE SET ...
```

There is a field in the second table table_2.status and I need

if the (**"lap", "tt"**) entry is in the first table, then update
**table_2.status =1**

if there are no records, then update
**table_2.status=0**

So far, I first do update table_2.status=0 and then it already goes

```
INSERT ...VALUES (...) ON CONFLICT ...DO UPDATE SET
```

If there was one unique field, then I would do an Update via

```
....SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 in (SELECT column1 FROM table2)....
```

but how can I do it with two unique fields.... I can't understand

UP

```
 UNIQUE INDEX table_1_idx ON public.table_1 USING btree (lap, tt);
 UNIQUE INDEX table_2_idx ON public.table_2 USING btree (lap, tt);
```

Comment: What are the 2 unique fields you are talking about ? I understand you only want to update table2.status according to the rows in table1.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).  There is no UPDATE statement after: " I would do an Update via...."

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.